# Is it possible to create an infinite scrolling screen in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

General question: Does tkinter support an infinite scrolling screen such as what you would see in flappy bird? If so, how?
Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad, and should probably be posted in another forum (eg reddit). However, it's worth mentioning that although it appears infinite, the way flappy bird was developed is a static page, and just moving bars going from one end to the other, and then returning to their original position

Comment: infinity scrolling image mostly uses two the same images. it draws one next to another. When first - on left side - is not visible then you move it to right side and it can be visible again after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The comments by @diev and @furas explain roughly how flappy bird is made.

You could theoretically make a side scroller using the canvas module, but it would be *much* easier to use a dedicated game making library, such as pygame.